# How to Register and Display Widget for Custom taxonomy

Tags: customization, widgets, taxonomy

I have registered a Custom Taxonomy Named as Album, Now i want to register and display a custom widget like category to display recent 'x' albums with thumbnail on my sidebar. 
Below is a piece of code, but its showing it like a tag cloud.

```
<?php 
add_action("widgets_init", array('Widget_Custom_tax_tag_cloud', 'register'));
class Widget_Custom_tax_tag_cloud {
    function control(){
        echo 'No control panel';
    }
    function widget($args){
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        echo $args['before_title'] . 'Your widget title' . $args['after_title'];
        $cloud_args = array('taxonomy' => 'Your taxonomy here');
        wp_tag_cloud( $cloud_args ); 
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
    function register(){
        register_sidebar_widget('Widget name', array('Widget_Custom_tax_tag_cloud', 'widget'));
        register_widget_control('Widget name', array('Widget_Custom_tax_tag_cloud', 'control'));
    }
}
?>
```

This is my site URL: http://pagalworldmp.com/

Answer (score 2):

There's at least 3 options:

1. You could take the code for the native [recent posts widget](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L779) and
   modify it in your child theme to work with your custom taxonomy.
2. You could create a new [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) using the tax parameters.
3. Or you could use a filter [`widget_posts_args`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/widget_posts_args) to modify the default output of the native recent posts widget so it outputs your custom taxonomy.

I suggest you look into the core and find the native recent posts widget or category widget and take a look at the code. Try wp-includes/default-widgets.php.